Is there a native git mechanism to update HEAD to point at a not-yet-existent branch or ref without side effects?
If I run git checkout --orphan my_new_branch, then .git/HEAD points to a ref that does not (yet) exist.
git checkout --orphan my_new_branch
Switched to a new branch 'my_new_branch'

cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/my_new_branch

git show-ref refs/heads/my_new_branch
# No output

ls .git/refs/heads/my_new_branch
ls: cannot access '.git/refs/heads/my_new_branch': No such file or directory


Mostly out of curiosity, I tried to replicate this state using update-ref and symbolic-ref, but git seems to disallow this:
git update-ref  HEAD 'refs/heads/my_new_branch'
fatal: refs/heads/my_new_branch: not a valid SHA1

git symbolic-ref HEAD 'ref: refs/heads/my_new_branch'
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/

Is there some other plumbing command invocation that can explicitly move HEAD to point at a non-existent ref, without all the other side effects of git checkout --orphan?
I am aware that I can just do echo "ref: refs/heads/my_new_branch" > .git/HEAD, but I am curious to learn about whether directly writing to the file is the only approach.
Output of git -v, in case the behavior is version-dependent:
git version 2.47.0


Try git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/my_new_branch

@phd That works. Updates to an unborn branch. Now the state of the branch you were on is in the index.

Be careful to switch back to the branch you were on or Git might complain that switching to some other branch or commit would would be overwritten.  But switching back and forth works.

@phd That works, thanks! I was close, but didn't quite get there on my own. :)
